# Correct layout for dictionary literals

Tags: python, dictionary, coding-style

I have seen a few different ways that people like to format dictionaries, but most people seem to follow 1 of 2 ways:

Option 1)

```
d = {
    'key1': 'value1',
    'key2': 'value2'
    }
```

Option 2)

```
d ={'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
```

In use both do the same thing, but is one more pythonic, is one a better way of formatting a dictionary, is one just plain incorrect?

I'm interested to know which way of formatting is most widely accepted and would be better to use in my scripts.

Before I'm told I haven't done much research, I did and it caused even more confusion, different sites, different people, different tutorials, often use different ways and I can't find anywhere that says "Do it like this, this is the correct syntax"

Comment: [Hope is is what you are looking for](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: @nu11p01n73R Layout of dictionaries is not covered in PEP8.

Comment: And as such, because there is no "authoritative" standing (ie. in PEP8), all answers for *which* format to choose are opinions.. I choose the form largely based on how it fits on a line, but no space after the = is hideous!

Comment: I've edited your title, because it's not about syntax (syntactically, both constructs are valid).

Comment: @user2864740: PEP does say something about the closing brace position (aligned either with the last or the first line).

Comment: @user2864740 It talks about it [here](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation). It doesn't explicitly mention dictionaries, no, but it it *is* talking about line continuations.

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8 helps detect such problems, but it doesn't offer much advice on how to correct them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It *is* talked about in PEP 8, in the [indentation](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) section.

> Continuation lines should align wrapped elements either vertically
>   using Python's implicit line joining inside parentheses, brackets and
>   braces, or using a hanging indent [5]

So dictionaries are covered there.

> ...brackets and *braces*, ...

And all it does is give ways to do the several kinds of multiline statement;

```
# Aligned with opening delimiter.
foo = long_function_name(var_one, var_two,
                         var_three, var_four)

# More indentation included to distinguish this from the rest.
def long_function_name(
        var_one, var_two, var_three,
        var_four):
    print(var_one)

# Hanging indents should add a level.
foo = long_function_name(
    var_one, var_two,
    var_three, var_four)
```

So in your examples;

```
d ={'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
```

is actually not adhering to PEP8 [*whitespace in expressions and statements*](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements), as you have missed out a space; it should be (note the extra space. Yes it's pedantic):

```
d = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
```

As for the multiline version, all the examples in PEP8 leave the closing bracket on the last line (but it does not specifically mention where it should go). There are some alternatives too, and which you choose seems to be simply a preference - [A Foolish Consistency is the Hobgoblin of Little Minds](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds) (also PEP8). The main rule is:

> When using a hanging indent the following considerations should be
>   applied; there should be no arguments on the first line and further
>   indentation should be used to clearly distinguish itself as a
>   continuation line.

Only the *hanging indent* and *aligned with opening delimiter* version apply here though.

```
# Aligned with opening delimiter.
d = {'key1': 'value1',
     'key2': 'value2'}

longerVariableName = {'key1': 'value1',
                      'key2': 'value2'}

# Hanging indents should add a level.
d = {
    'key1': 'value1',
    'key2': 'value2'}

longerVariableName = {
    'key1': 'value1',
    'key2': 'value2'}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some aspects not covered in PEP8.

1. Renaming a variable or a function name should not break formatting. The new name can be shorter or longer.
2. Adding/removing an item should not affect lines immediately above or below. You want `git diff` - or other VCS - to show only the changes.

If you agree with these points, you will probably want to write dicts that does not fit on one short line like this:

```
my_first_dict_today = {
    key1: value1,
    key2: value2,
    key3: value3,
    }

# note the comma after value3
```

The closing bracket may be lined up either with the last line or the first line, PEP8 allows both.

Answer (score 1):

They are both correct ways. But if you have initialize a dictionary with 100 pairsin it. The first option makes it more readible.

The seccond option is good for small dictionaries, with one or two pairs

Answer (score 0):

To the interpreter, they are equivalent. In any given use case, choose whichever syntax you think would be easier for another human to read.

This is subjective, but I personally would only use the second syntax for the tiniest of dictionaries.

Comment: So it really is down to which would be easier for a human to read in a given instance? Eg. for comparisons I'd like to use option 1 because you can read down a column, but for something a phone book where it doesn't matter then option 2 would suffice?